# Link cell with Excel Shape

Tags: excel, shapes, vba

In excel, we insert a shape, and we can link it to a cells value, by selecting shape and typing the
cell reference in formula bar. I want to know: How can we do that programmatically. Like

```
For Each shape As Excel.Shape In workshet.Shapes
  'is there something like shape.Formula or any method from which I can do the above
   task.         
Next
```

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/display-cell-contents-in-a-shape-or-text-box-HP005201093.aspx) is what I want to do programmatically

It's been days now , I am searching it. Really Need help, Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use Select to apply formulas to Shapes. Select should be avoided wherever possible as it bloats code, and can have unintended consequences - for example triggering Events

Instead you can work with the Formula directly by using DrawingOBject, see`FormApp`which also will let you manipulate existing formula (ie add 6 cell to A2 to make it A8, A12 to A18 etc). The second code routine `FormAdd` makes this adjustment, it works on both cell addresses and range names

```
Sub FormApp()
    Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        'formula
         Shp.DrawingObject.Formula = "=A1"
        'range name
        Shp.DrawingObject.Formula = "=RangeName"
    Next
End Sub

Sub FormAdd()
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim rng1 As Range
    For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Set rng1 = Nothing
        If Len(Shp.DrawingObject.Formula) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rng1 = Range(Shp.DrawingObject.Formula)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then Shp.DrawingObject.Formula = "=" & rng1.Offset(6, 0).Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 I was hoping someone would identify the object that contains the `.Formula` property.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option is to programatically select the shape first, then apply the formula

```
Dim Shp as Shape
For each Shp in ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Shp.Select
    Selection.Formula = "=A1"
Next
```

Or course this will error if a shape on the sheet does not support the `.Formula` property