# Excel vba Change shape formula without selecting shape

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the formula within a shape without selecting it but keep getting a run-time error.

Below are some of the code I've tried so far:

```
    Sheets("Quote").Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 87")).Formula = " =CommAnnualOutput"
    Sheets("Quote").Shapes("Rectangle 87").Formula = " =CommAnnualOutput"
    Sheets("Quote").Shapes("Rectangle 87").DrawingObjects.Formula = " =CommAnnualOutput"
```

None of these seem to work. Is there a way to change the formula without selecting the shape first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the answer to your question here:

[Link cell with Excel Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189317/link-cell-with-excel-shape)

Good luck

Comment: I had seen this question but it didn't seem to work. It turns out it was because I'd left a space between before the second equals sign which was giving a run-time error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You missed two characters on your last try. That would be

```
Sheets("Quote").Shapes("Rectangle 87").DrawingObject.Formula = "=CommAnnualOutput"
```