# Insert Formula to a shape object C# to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have created a shape object in excel using C# and I want the text in a cell to appear in the shape. When I recorded the macro in excel, I got the below formula

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle1")).Select
        Selection.Formula = "=$D$21"
```

Can anyone help me on how to reproduce the above code in C#? Below is the C# code that controls excel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class ExcelTest : Form
    {

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();


        public ExcelTest()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("F:\\YourExcelSheet.xlsx");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = excel.ActiveSheet as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
            excel.Visible = true;
            Range MyCells = ws.Cells;
            MyCells.Item[1, "A"] = "Test";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 30, 100, 300, 100);
            shp.Name = "Shape1";
            shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.Gray.ToArgb();
            shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb();
            shp.TextEffect.Text = Convert.ToString(MyCells.Item[1, "A"].Value);            
            //InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using c# to communicate with Excel?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape Shp = ws.Shapes.AddShape(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 30, 100, 300, 100); I use this to add shape. If I use  s1.TextEffect.Text ="Text"; i can get the text within the shape. But that's not required. i need to link it to a range

Comment: btw, i think u are getting neg rep because you aren't showing enough code, like the c# that you already have.  I would like to replicate what you are doing so that I can apply what I know, especially about Excel, into my version.  But that's difficult without your code.

Comment: Hi, added a sample code in the question. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my - try this:

```
shp.DrawingObject.Formula = "=A1";
```

I found the answer here: [Stack Overflow: Link cell with Excel Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189317/link-cell-with-excel-shape)

Comment: yes... errr no... no intellisense in c# for DrawingObject... and nor do you get intellisense in VBA (I tried both) - but in both places , successful compile and the formula set works.

Comment: No worries - I really dig c# and Excel.  However, can you please mark this as answered?  Thx kindly! :)